# How can I get a hyperlink to post a form to the link target?

Tags: http

I am a site, Site A, with a small simple hyperlink to a completly external site, SiteB, that hosts an electronic magazine for Site A.  Clicking the link takes the user to SiteB, where they are given a logon page.  I need to tell SiteB that uses from SiteA are already authenticated.  SiteB allows this by SiteA posting a form with user identity data to access the magazine, instead of a normal GET request from the hypelink.

Is there any way I should be doing this rather than my envisaged, rather kludgy, approach.  I have set the hypelink to point to a local form, which is never visible to the user.  When hit, the form populates itself with correct user id data, and then posts itself to SiteB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript. Something like this in jQuery:

```
$('#myLink').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#myForm')
        .attr('action', url)
        .submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd likely be better off using a cookie. If you pass a token in the url, the user might (even unintentionally) copy the url and send to a friend, and it will have their auth info still in it. The cookie will remain on the user's machine, so can't be accidently copied to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be talking about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on , but I personally find your solution good enough for all practical purposes. Mike's JavaScript will give you the same results, I have personally used this approach and everything was A-OK.